# How to do right join in LINQ when provided a search filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

In my List page within the Application for the below entity Service Entry, I need to display all service entries and include the column ServiceTechnicanID which will some times be NULL.  When its NUll, I display an NA. Until this point the query pulls out the correct records. The problem occurs when a search filter is provided in the query. If I pass in a search filter to search service entries by Technican ID/Full Name, I get all records.

```
ServiceEntry
ID
TechnicanID
ServiceTechnicianID

User
ID
FirstName
LastName
FullName (DBComputedColumn)
```

Query

```
   var list = (from se in db.ServiceEntry
                        join u in db.User on se.ServiceTechnician equals u.ID into joinUserEntry
                        from u2 in joinUserEntry.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join r in db.RunLogEntry on se.RunLogEntryID equals r.ID into joinRunLogEntry
                        from r2 in joinRunLogEntry.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join s in db.System1 on se.SystemID equals s.ID
                        join p in db.Platform1 on s.PlatformID equals p.ID
                        where (
                            ((se.RunLogEntryID == 0 || se.RunLogEntryID != null))
                                 && ((serviceEntryFilter.ID.HasValue == false) || (se.ID == serviceEntryFilter.ID.Value && serviceEntryFilter.ID.HasValue == true))
                                && ((serviceEntryFilter.ServiceDateTime.HasValue == false) || (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(se.ServiceDateTime) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(serviceEntryFilter.ServiceDateTime) && serviceEntryFilter.ServiceDateTime.HasValue == true))
                                && ((serviceEntryFilter.RunDate.HasValue == false) || (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r2.RunDate) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(serviceEntryFilter.RunDate) && serviceEntryFilter.RunDate.HasValue == true))
                            //&& ((serviceEntryFilter.ServiceTechnician == null) ||   (u2.FullName.Contains(serviceEntryFilter.ServiceTechnician.Trim()) && serviceEntryFilter.ServiceTechnician != null))
                                && ((serviceEntryFilter.ServiceTechnician == null) || ((u2.FullName.Contains(serviceEntryFilter.ServiceTechnician.Trim()))))
                                && (
                                        ((ServiceEntryStatus == "O" && se.ServiceRequestClosed == false) ||
                                          (ServiceEntryStatus == "C" && se.ServiceRequestClosed == true) ||
                                          (ServiceEntryStatus == "A")
                                        )
                                   )
                                       && (
                                        ((ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == null) ||
                                         (ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == "N" && se.ReliabilityRecord == false) ||
                                          (ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == "Y" && se.ReliabilityRecord == true) ||
                                          (ServiceEntryReliabilityRecord == "A")
                                        )
                                    )
                                && (
                                        ((ServiceEntryReconciled == null) ||
                                         (ServiceEntryReconciled == "N" && se.Reconciled == false) ||
                                          (ServiceEntryReconciled == "Y" && se.Reconciled == true) ||
                                          (ServiceEntryReconciled == "A")
                                        )
                                    )
                                             && (
                                        ((ActiveServiceEntry == null) ||
                                         (ActiveServiceEntry == "N" && se.Active == false) ||
                                          (ActiveServiceEntry == "Y" && se.Active == true) ||
                                          (ActiveServiceEntry == "A")
                                        )
                                    )

                                        && (
                                      (s.PlatformID == platformID) || (platformID == 0)
                                   )
                                                                                  && ((serviceEntryFilter.System == null) || (systems.Contains(s.SystemFullName)))

                            )
                        orderby se.ID descending
                        select new ServiceSearchEntry()
                        {
                            ID = se.ID,
                            ServiceDateTime = se.ServiceDateTime,
                            Technician = (u2.FullName == null ? "N/A" : u2.FullName),
                            System = s.SystemFullName,
                            ReasonForFailure = se.ReasonForFailure,
                            RunDate = (r2 == null ? (DateTime?)null : r2.RunDate),
                            Platform = p.PlatformName
                        });
```

Comment: You've got big formatting problems with your code, could you fix those? I tried to myself but ran into problems at `where ( &&` in your query... it looks like you miss-copied something.

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to your initial problem, but you may want to use `u2.FullName ?? "N/A"` to simplify your `ServiceTechnician` calculation.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce I had not posted the entire query, sorry about that. I posted it correctly now and the entire query.